# How to fix 'ClassNotFoundError' when loading classes from a folder outside the classpath

Tags: java, file, class, classloading

I'm writing a module system that loads modules with additional functionality to my Spigot plugin. When I try to load a class dynamically from my modules, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

I am using a classloader to load the jar file of my modules, which are stored in a seperate folder also called "modules". I have looked for several tutorials regarding classloaders, and as far as I am aware I am doing nothing wrong in this bit of code.

Here's my code:

```java
        File modulesFolder = new File(instance.getDataFolder(), "modules/");
        if (!modulesFolder.exists())
            modulesFolder.mkdirs();

        System.out.println("scanning modules folder...");
        for (File f:modulesFolder.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                String moduleName = LCStringUtils.trimString(f.getName(), ".jar");
                Class<?> moduleClass = null;
                try {
                    ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                            new URL[] {f.toURI().toURL()},
                            getClass().getClassLoader()
                        );

                    moduleClass = Class.forName("net.libercraft." + moduleName.toLowerCase() + "." + moduleName, true, loader);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (moduleClass == null || !Module.class.isAssignableFrom(moduleClass))
                    continue;
                System.out.println(moduleClass.getName());
            }
        }
```

I'm quite sure that the class should be there. The code is able to load the name of the file, which it needs to get the classpath. And as you can see in the file structure for the LiberEffects.jar, it does also contain a class called LiberEffects. I have placed this jar file in the modules folder, but when it tries to load the net.libercraft.libereffects.LiberEffects class it throws the error.

File structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr99N.png

Comment: Have you printed the names (file and what is passed to forName) to see if they are correct?

Answer (score 0):

¿Have you tried putting the entire path of the directory instead of `"modules/"`? For example `C:\Users\userName\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Erste_projeckt\modules`.

Comment: I changed the file variable to this:

File modulesFolder = new File("/home/spigot/server/plugins/LiberCore/modules/");


and that seems to have fixed the issue! thanks for the suggestion.